# Processing string faster

Tags: string, optimization, coldfusion

Based on [Why is my coldfusion code 100x faster now on string processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707919/why-is-my-coldfusion-code-100x-faster-now-on-string-processing)

I am wondering if this

```
<CFSET LocalTextString = LocalTextString & DriverID & TabChar & LocalSSN & TabChar & FirstName & CarriageReturn & LineFeed>

<CFSET TextString = TextString & LocalTextString>
```

Is equivalent to

```
<cfset Textstring &= LocalTextString & DriverID & TabChar & LocalSSN & TabChar & FirstName & CarriageReturn & LineFeed>
```

Or if something like

```
<cfset Textstring &= (LocalTextString & DriverID & TabChar & LocalSSN & TabChar & FirstName & CarriageReturn & LineFeed)>
```

Has to be done

?

Comment: Why don't you just save both approaches to a file, run 'em, and decompile the results & check? http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/11/how-to-see-java-that-your-cfml-compiles.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<CFSET LocalTextString = LocalTextString & DriverID & TabChar & LocalSSN & TabChar & FirstName & CarriageReturn & LineFeed>
<CFSET TextString = TextString & LocalTextString>
```

is equivalent to

```
<cfset Textstring &= LocalTextString & DriverID & TabChar & LocalSSN & TabChar & FirstName & CarriageReturn & LineFeed>
```

The extra parenthesis are not required.